# Swagger Models for Throwable and StackTraceElement

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

Swagger UI shows Models for StackTraceElement and Throwable objects. 
I would like to configure it so that these models are not shown.
[image]

I have tried annotating the custom class for exceptions with @JsonIgnore:

```
/** Custom exception class to handle business validation exceptions. */
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"detailMessage", "cause", "stackTrace", "suppressed"})
public class PatientBundleException extends Exception {

  @JsonIgnore
  public PatientBundleException(String exceptionMessage) {
    super(exceptionMessage);
  }
}
```

Here is my Docket:

```
  @Bean
  public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("..."))
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build()
        .apiInfo(apiInfo());
```

I am using springfox version 2.9.2

If anyone can help assist with configuring Swagger UI to not show models for Throwable and StackTraceElement, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, it turns out I was extending "Exception" on my model, when I didn't need to.